# How to create Currency instance with non ISO 3166 country like en_UK?

Tags: java, android, locale

In my app, I get the user's default locale using `Locale.getDefault()` and then pass that to `Currency.getInstance(Locale)`. It mostly works, but I have started getting reports from users which show the following `IllegalArgumentException` in the stack trace:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ISO 3166
>   country: en_UK at java.util.Currency.getInstance(Currency.java:81) at
>   org.

I expected Android to only return valid locales, but that is apparently not the case.

How do I handle such cases to make sure I only get valid ISO 3166 locales? The easy way will be to handle this special case, but I would rather use a generic solution if there is one.

Anyone have experience with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [ISO 3166](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html) two-letter abbreviation for the UK is not `UK`, the correct id is `GB`.  `UK` is there for compatibility reasons (a mistake made in the past).

I did look for other exeptions but did not find any, so for now i would just handle the special case.

```
Locale loc = new Locale("en","UK"); // test code

if(loc.getCountry().equals("UK")){
    loc = new Locale(loc.getLanguage(), "GB");
    }
Currency cur = Currency.getInstance(loc);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting same exception when using ES and PT, I have checked the ISO 3166 list you have mentioned, the list have both the locale. Then why the exception occured?

Comment: Please post your question and the code you used, as a new Question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with ES Mani.  Similar code to the original question above...

currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());

Answer (score 2):

`Currency.getInstance(...)` expects a locale of the form "en_US", however, `Locale.getDefault()` does not always return a locale of this form.

To prevent crashes in your app, you can use something like this:

```
public static String getCurrencySymbol(){
    String cursym;
    try {
        cursym = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getSymbol();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        cursym = "?"; // default symbol
    }
    return cursym;
}
```

You can try to figure out a better way to get the most appropriate symbol, or just let the user choose one.

Answer (score 1):

Your users (with dev settings enabled) or testers have manually set a weird and invalid country. This bug occurred to us, but it turned out our testers had configured Appium to set the device locale to `en-UK` :).

A regular user can not select en-UK or any other invalid locale.

Answer (score -1):

```
String symbolLocale ="";
int localeLength = mLocale.split("-").length;

if (localeLength == 2) {
    symbolLocale = new Locale(
        mLocale.split("-", 2)[0], 
        mLocale.split("-", 2)[1]
    );
} else if (localeLength == 3) {
    symbolLocale = new Locale(
        mLocale.split("-", 3)[0] + "-" + 
        mLocale.split("-", 3)[1], 
        mLocale.split("-", 3)[2]
    );
}

symbolString = Currency.getInstance(symbolLocale).getSymbol(symbolLocale);
```

Comment: Please add what this code does, what it's for and how it solves OP's problem. Else it's not very useful.